# PHP: Preventing SQL Injection when using LIKE selector

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I have a PHP Script that uses a very simple search statement using mysqli. This is the statement :

```
SELECT * FROM JobTracker WHERE JobName LIKE'%$jobName%'
```

Now I want to prevent SQL injection but I can't figure out the syntax.

I've tried `LIKE '%?%'` and `LIKE '%' . ? . '%'` and`LIKE '%' + ? + '%'`

but none worked. What is the correct syntax for this SQL statement that will prevent injection?

Comment: Here, see this article on SO =>  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Comment: That doesn't apply to the LIKE selector since I want to use the '%' to get values that contain the string

Comment: In addition to preventing SQL injection, you might also want to stem denial of service opportunities.  If someone inputs a blank string, you'll return the whole table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two choices:

- Special characters `%` and `_` should be *allowed* as wildcards in input:

  ```
  ... LIKE CONCAT('%', ?, '%')
  ```
- Wildcard characters *should not* be allowed:

  ```
  ... LIKE ?

  $jobName = '%'.str_replace(array("_","%"),array("\\_","\\%"),$jobName).'%';
  ```

Comment: This (answer) should probably be added to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php then, since OP stated that it doesn't apply to the LIKE selector, as per [`OP's comment`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24867280/php-preventing-sql-injection-when-using-like-selector#comment38620190_24867280)

Comment: If you can't use wildcards you may as well use an `=` operator. Then you can use `%` and `_` as their original meaning. Sorry, I meant that in the case that you are not concating `%` to the input as per your second example.

Answer (score 0):

```
$jobName = real_escape_string($jobName);

$stmt = mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM JobTracker WHERE JobName LIKE '%?%'");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $jobName);
$stmt->execute();
```

PDO statements are really good for preventing SQL injection.

Comment: when you say it doesn't work, how do you mean, is the statement running, is there an error, or have you tried inputting SQL and it's accepting it?

Comment: Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object. That's the error it gave me.

Comment: what version of PHP are you running?

Comment: Putting `?` in quotes will be threat as a string and will never be associaded to a bound param